# How to update arrays of document within mongodb douments? Vapor 4, MongoKitten

Tags: arrays, swift, mongodb, vapor, mongokitten

I have a MongoDB collection which stores, countries, each country has an array of regions and each region has an array of crags and each crag has an array of sectors. Here are the structs which represent this set up.

```swift
struct Country: Codable, Hashable{
    var name: String
    var description: String?
    var imageUrl: String?
    var regions: [Region]
}
struct Region: Codable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var descripton: String
    var imageUrl: String
    var crags: [Crag]?
}
struct Crag: Codable,Hashable {
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var imageUrl: String
    var sectors: [Sector]?
}
struct Sector:Codable,Hashable {
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var imageUrl: String
}
```

I am using a Vapor 4 and the mongokitten libray backend and want to be able to add items to the various arrays, for example I would like to add a crag to the crags array in a region. It needs to be added to a sepcific country, then a specific region within that countries array of regions.

These are some of the options I have tried.

```swift
countryCol.updateOne(where: ["name":country], to: ["$addToSet":["regions.$[region].crags":doc], "arrayFilters":["region.name":region]]

countryCol.updateOne(where: ["name":country, "regions.$" : region], to: ["$addToSet":["crags":doc]])
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?